# Which is the event of Radio Button List which is similar to Check Changed event of Radio button

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am creating a Web form in which I have taken a radio button list comprises of 2 list items: AccountId and Account Number. I want to fire the event of the Radio Button list that i have used but i am not able to find the correct one. I can only find the SelectedIndexChange event and TextEvent which is not working.

I just want that when I use any list item of the radio button list, the required action should takes place as when I select Accountnumber as a list item from the Radio Button list, then  certain fields that I have used in my webform like Name, Age, and Personal Info should get disabled. If I select AccountId from the radio button list item, then other fields that I have used like subaccount, Subacountinfo should get disabled.

I am not able to do it because I am not able to find the correct event of the radio button list to fire. Please help

Comment: You could bind the enabled state of your form items to the IsChecked state of your radiobuttons directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust  `AutopostBack="true"` and `SelectIndexChanged event` to your control

Aspx

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
```

Code Behind

```
void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    if(RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "")
    {
          //Define your treatment 
          ....     

    }
}
```

Nota : OnSelectIndexChanged is not raised if AutoPostBack is not defined

Comment: I understand that the selectedindexChanged event will be fired if AutoPostBack is set to true. But I dont want to use it because I have to Post Back the page everytime the event is fired, which is not good. Can I use Java Script to hide or make visible certain field?

Comment: Yes you can also use javascript, try with onchange event and GetElementById based on ClientId of your radiobuttonlist

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the Events in [RadioButtonList Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx).

You can use [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event.